# Can't add scripts on VM itself as pre/post patch scripts in GCE VM Manager Patch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

On the VM I am trying to patch, I have two scripts in my main user's home directory: `/home/myuser/pre-patch.sh` and `/home/myuser/post-patch.sh`. Both have been `chmod +x`'ed.

I am trying to set these scripts as the pre-patch and post-patch scripts for a job schedule / patch job in Google Cloud > VM Manager > Patch, but when entering their paths, I see a red exclamation mark and am unable to save the job.

[image: Screenshot showing the problem]

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/create-patch-job?&_ga=2.96437791.-2048265106.1699986342#add-scripts) states that it should be possible to host the script on the VM itself:

> These script files can either be stored on the VM or in a versioned Cloud Storage bucket.

How do I go about this? Do I have to use the command line for it? If so, can I simply edit the existing job (so that the other settings are still there) rather than creating one from scratch?

Comment: I do not recommend storing files that the system needs to access in user home directories. The system is not the user and you can have access rights problems. Create a folder for your scripts.

Comment: Interesting point @JohnHanley, where would you put this folder instead?

Comment: In the root directory named something like `/myscipts` with suitable access permissions and ownership.

Answer (score 1):

UI might force you to use cloud storage. Therefore try the following

eg command

```
gcloud compute os-config patch-jobs execute --instance-filter-all --pre-patch-linux-executable="/home/doggie/script.sh"
```

Documentation:https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/os-config/patch-jobs/execute

[image]

Comment: This sounds good, but it would only execute the patch job once with the extra pre-patch script right? I suspect what I have to do is run the `patch-deployments update` command and pass some file to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cloud storage, the script should exists in this particular format:

gs://bucketname/filepath

Comment: Sure - that's if I want to put the script on a bucket. But if I want to leave the script on the actual VM, how should I format the path?